# Python Telegram bot return list of variables

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I have a Python telegram bot up and running. Now I have implemented a new command that retrieves values from an API and send them through bot.send.message. Here you have the code snippet of the mentioned command,

```
def my_command(bot, update):
    request = requests.get("https://my_site.com/api").json()
    value1 = request[0]
    value2 = request[1]
    value3 = request[2]
    array_of_values = (value1, value2, value3)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text = array_of_values)
```

This prints the following in telegram

["value1", "value2", "value3"]

But What I want is the following

value 1
value 2
value 3

I'm clearly not managing well telegram output using the bot.send_message. I have the same issue in other commands as well. How can I do it? Do I have to return the value in the function and then use the bot.send_message or is it a matter of pretty formatting?

Thanks!
Eric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints ["value1", "value2", "value3"] because `bot.send_message(text="")` takes string, not a array, so it typically just prints what you've written there.

You can do it in two ways,

Manually like the code below.

```
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text = value1 + "\n" + value2 + "\n" + value3)
```

Or

```
    array_of_values = (value1, value2, value3)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text = "\n".join(array_of_values))
```

Note that `"\n"` is added for linebreak. You can replace it with `%0A` if line breaking isn't working with you.

Comment: That's perfect. It work for me. But I have to ask. Is there a better way to output telegram messages? Would you consider using markdown?

Comment: Yes you can use Markdown.
`bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=" *bold*  Example message", 
             parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)`  

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/shaunlebron/746476e6e7a4d698b373) for linebreaks in markdowns.

Also, you can use HTML by changing to ParseMode.HTML instead of Markdown. Glad to help, would appreciate if you marked it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help. I will probably move to Markdown or HTML. I have marked your answer